# Different Color in The Active Navigation Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I would like to change the background color of the menu button when I'm on the page

[image]

This is my code:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

I know that I have to use Javascript but I don't now the code to change the class when the link is active.

Comment: Is this a one-pager (the links look like it), or are those links leading to different pages in real life?

Comment: Yes sorry, these are links to different pages, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use PHP for this. On each page add a variable with the name of the page assigned to it e.g.

```
<?php $page = "News"; ?>
```

Then you can add conditional statements that will add an active class to the navigation link that relates to the page you are viewing e.g.

```
<ul>
  <li><a <?php echo ($page == "Home") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a <?php echo ($page == "News") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="news.php">News</a></li>
  <li><a <?php echo ($page == "Contact") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a <?php echo ($page == "About") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="about.php">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you don't recognise the PHP code, it is just a shorthand version of an if statement.

Answer (score -1):

Make a different css page, then link it to that page, and just copy and paste everything.

Comment: I tried to use this code but the background doesn't change when I'm on the page. If I click on the second link (news) the color green remain on the link "home". The class "active" doesn't switch on the "news" link